Wine is unable to access path for Adobe DNG Converter
wine "/home/myuser/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe DNG Converter/Adobe DNG Converter.exe"  "-fl -mp P:\\DNG-convert\\ "

However I'm getting the following error window:

I have mapped drive P to /home/myuser/Pictures/ directory where I have a directory DNG-convert containing photos I want to convert. This is the same directory as the input by default.
I want to run Adobe DNG Converter in terminal, but I cannot feed a directory parameter.
Adobe DNG Converter cannot find P:\\DNG-convert\\ 

What am I doing wrong? Why this path cannot be found by Adobe DNG Converter?
Otherwise Adobe DNG Converter is working well if I'm launching just the EXE.
I tried:
alias dng='wine "/home/myuser/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe DNG Converter/Adobe DNG Converter.exe"'
~/Pictures/DNG-convert$ dng -fl -mp ./DSC05450.ARW

but it does not show any message or error, and does not convert the image.
